# How to fix Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) error?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

In my next js 13 app whenever i use a package related to image (in my case a blurhash package called [blurhash-from-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blurhash-from-url)) it throws an error.

```
error ./node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp-darwin-x64.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

it's not just this package, anytime i try to use blurhash related packages it throws the same error. i tried to add a loader of `custom` in my `nextjs.config` but did nothing.

```
export default function page() {

  const [blurs, setBlurs] = useState([]);

  async function getBlurhash(url) {
    const output = await blurhashFromURL(url);
    setBlurs((prev) => [...prev, output]);
    console.log(output);
  }

useEffect(() => {
    getBlurhash(
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1690263914767-963579f9620c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60"
    );
},[]);

return (
   ...rest
);

}
```

what does this error mean and how can i get rid of it?

NB: i've looked up other stackoverflow and github questions somewhat related to this question but it didn't help. so that's why i'm creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the package you have mentioned. The package uses a dependency called `sharp` that does all the processing, and it requires nodejs runtime.

If you run into a similar issue. In your webpack config, add the following lines. This makes sure the `sharp` will be excluded during the bundling.

```
{    
  externals: {
    sharp: 'commonjs sharp'
  }
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#bundlers)

Here is another [useful resource](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/webpack) from Nextjs docs